# How to create encapsulated multipart with Apache httpclient

Tags: java, apache, http-post, httpclient

I need to create and send an HttpPost containing form data, which should look like this:

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfREN.png)

I'm using apache's httpmime and httpclient (version 4.5.10):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my code:

```
...
ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("multipart/form-data");        

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

HttpEntity entity = builder.addTextBody("Name 123", "Value 123").setContentType(contentType).build();
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient myClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
response = myClient.execute(httppost, context);
...
```

The code is working (no exception is raised) but the post looks like this in whireshark:
[How it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scWCZ.png)

As you can see, there is just a data-block but no "encapsulated multipart part"-parts. The web-application, which is receiving the post-data, needs the data in the "format" shown in the first screenshot.
-> What do I need to do to accomplish this?

I tried as well another approach, but it did not solve my problem (no "encapsulated multipart part"-parts):

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name 123", "Value 123"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpClient myClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
response = myClient.execute(httppost, context);
```

Any help is highly appreciated!